# Display value of string in label

Tags: c#

I have a label on my form which i want to be filled with the value of a string, but i can't get it working. This is my code;

In the function Execute, i call the function `ShowText((string)result[3])`, result is the object I fetch from a database query. This is the function ShowText;

```
public void ShowText(string message)
{
    label4.Text = message;
}
```

I'm getting a NullReferenceException error, what am i doing wrong?

result[3];
[image]
label4
[image]

code;

```
    Execute();
    InitializeComponent();
    var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => Execute());
    aTimer.Interval = 300000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

}
public void Execute()
{
    int Tijd;
    int Videolengte;
    string resultaat;
    string URL = "";

    Database db = new Database(CONNECTION_STRING);
    object[] result = db.GetFirstRecord();

    if (result == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //laat app steeds 50ms slapen zodat overgang van muziek mooi is
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 90);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 80);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 70);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 60);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 50);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 40);
        //start youtube video op
        URL = (string)result[1];
        Process browser = Process.Start(@"chrome.exe", "http:\\www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + URL);
        ShowText((string)result[3]);
        //laat app steeds 50ms slapen zodat overgang van muziek mooi is
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 30);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 20);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 10);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 0);
        //bepaald tijd die applicatie moet slapen
        resultaat = (string)result[2];
        Videolengte = Convert.ToInt32(resultaat);
        Tijd = Videolengte * 1000;
        //laat app slapen tot lengte van liedje
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Tijd);
        //laat app steeds 50ms slapen zodat overgang van muziek mooi is
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 10);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 20);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 30);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 40);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 50);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 60);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 70);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 80);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 90);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Audio.SetApplicationVolume(APP, 100);
        //Kill alle google extensies
        Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        foreach (Process p in localByName)
        {
            p.Kill();
        }
        //verwijder record uit database
        //deleteRow();

    }
}
public void ShowText(string message)
{
    label5.Text = message;
}
private void deleteRow()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Tracks ORDER BY Tijdstip", conn))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE TOP(1) FROM Tracks", conn))
            {
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        //Het is niet gelukt om het record uit de database te verwijderen
    }
}

private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Execute();
}

private Process GetWindowProcess(string windowTitle)
{
    foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
    {
        if (proc.MainWindowTitle.IndexOf(windowTitle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
        {
            return proc;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: you are on a WPF or a Web application?

Comment: Does `label4` exist? Is `result[3]` something other than null? Where is the exception being thrown?

Comment: The exception you're getting would tell me that there is nothing there. Debug, trace it backwards...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on it and have a look at the values - you'll soon see what's wrong most probably!

Comment: Just check whether `result[3]` or `label4` is null.

Comment: @Julián Urbano DBNull != null.

Comment: @lomed that assumes `result` is the direct result from the DB and not something else, maybe an array he set somewhere before

Comment: See the the images ive added to the OP

Comment: @Julián Urbano you are right.

Comment: @joostmakaay the code we need to see is the code that generates your graphical interface, because `label4` is null.

Comment: See my comment on Micheal Perrenoud's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're either getting it here:

```
ShowText((string)result[3])
```

because `result` is `null`, or you're getting it here:

```
label4.Text = message;
```

because `label4` is `null`.

It's most likely that `result` is `null`; especially if it's coming from the database.

---

**UPDATE:** now that all the code has been added, just move the call to `Execute` ***after*** the call to `InitializeComponent`. You see, `InitializeComponent` creates all of the stuff you dropped on the form in the WYSIWYG designer.

Comment: @joostmakaay, as I stated. If it's happening on that line then `label4` is `null`. I don't know where that field comes from, but it's definitely `null` right now.

Comment: I've declared the label4 in the FormMain Designer, the text in the properties window is set on label5, how could it be null then?

Comment: @joostmakaay, I'll be honest, I don't know. However, go through all of your code and see if you're trying to build a `new` label for `label4` and end up assigning `null`. It's odd, but it's tracable somewhere in your code.

Comment: @joostmakaay probably `label4` is not the label you think it is, but some other. Go to the windows form designer and check it again

Comment: these are all the labels i have in my code, under the FormMain.Designer.cs        `private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Label label5; `

Comment: @joostmakaay yes, you have them declared in your class, but not necessarily initialized, that's why it is null.

Comment: And how do i do that?

Comment: @joostmakaay, somewhere you need to say `label4 = new Label();`.

Comment: The call to Execute that call ShowText is made before the call to InitializeComponent.

Comment: @Steve, thanks a lot. The OP apparently added the entire set of code after I was working with him. That is 100% the cause of the issue!